# Can we use CORS policy to restrict API calls from native mobile app?

Tags: http, mobile, api, cors

We can use CORS to restrict API calls to a specific host in a web app. How to do the same for native mobile app?

I want to restrict API calls from my app alone.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: You are most likely looking for something like API access tokens: https://auth0.com/docs/secure/tokens/access-tokens If a user misuses or leaks the token to an attacker, simply block access with this token.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

CORS doesn't prevent anything, and it doesn't protect the server. It simply tells a *conforming* client (a browser) what is permitted for the protection of the browser's *user*; CORS is a way to carefully make holes in the browser's **Same-Origin Policy**. Additionally, CORS headers are advisory, in that they don't actually prevent anything from happening. They make it so that a malicious attacker can't fool an innocent victim's browser into making certain requests (or, more often, using the responses to such requests) that the user wouldn't want the browser to make. A browser's user could, if it was wanted, open up the browser's dev console and make the request anyhow. Similarly, the user could export the request (cookies and all) to `curl` and - potentially after making more changes - send it from there.

Any non-conforming client (such as in a mobile app, or just a shell script invoking `curl`), can and usually will completely ignore CORS. Such clients don't have a Same-Origin Policy to begin with, so there's nothing for CORS to make holes in and therefore it does nothing.

Comment: But how toallow calls from my native app alone ? what if xyz app try to call my api ? for example login api CBHacking @BenjaminH

Comment: @Yuvaraj This is a very common question on this site, and the simple answer is that it's impossible. You can require that the client (as opposed to the user) also authenticate to the service, often via something like a TLS client certificate, but if the attacker can examine your client it's impossible to hide a secret so well that an attacker could never find it, while still allowing your client to know that secret. Put another way, anything that your client (native app) can do, I can write an app that does the exact same thing, and it's impossible for your server to tell them apart.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible using http headers alone. CORS only applies to browsers, not to any other clients.

If you want to restrict api calls to your app, you need to implement some form of authentication. However, if your app is publicly available you have no way of keeping an api-key or something similar a secret if it is not unique per app installation.

Comment: "...if it is not unique per app installation." Now how can we handle the process of installation of the app on the user's phone in order to manage/generate a secret key that will be use to make API call to our server?

Comment: You could, for example, have each user register himself.